# iOS objective c data is not saving in sqlite3 database

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite, cart

```
[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[self.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"cartdb.sql"]];
```

Data is not saving in `sqlite3` database. `BOOL openDatabaseResult` is showing no and `sqlite3` database is showing null

The query :

```
query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into cartProductInfo(null, '%@', '%@', %d)", self.information.text, @"productid", [self.priceDisplayLabel.text intValue]
```

The code of db

```
-(void)runQuery:(const char *)query isQueryExecutable:(BOOL)queryExecutable{
// Create a sqlite object.
sqlite3 *sqlite3Database;

// Set the database file path.
NSString *databasePath = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[self.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"cartdb.sql"]];

// Initialize the results array.
if (self.arrResults != nil) {
    [self.arrResults removeAllObjects];
    self.arrResults = nil;
}
self.arrResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Initialize the column names array.
if (self.arrColumnNames != nil) {
    [self.arrColumnNames removeAllObjects];
    self.arrColumnNames = nil;
}
self.arrColumnNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


// Open the database.
BOOL openDatabaseResult = sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &sqlite3Database);
if(openDatabaseResult == SQLITE_OK) {
    // Declare a sqlite3_stmt object in which will be stored the query after having been compiled into a SQLite statement.
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    // Load all data from database to memory.
    BOOL prepareStatementResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite3Database, query, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL);
    if(prepareStatementResult == SQLITE_OK) {
        // Check if the query is non-executable.
        if (!queryExecutable){
            // In this case data must be loaded from the database.

            // Declare an array to keep the data for each fetched row.
            NSMutableArray *arrDataRow;

            // Loop through the results and add them to the results array row by row.
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                // Initialize the mutable array that will contain the data of a fetched row.
                arrDataRow = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                // Get the total number of columns.
                int totalColumns = sqlite3_column_count(compiledStatement);

                // Go through all columns and fetch each column data.
                for (int i=0; i<totalColumns; i++){
                    // Convert the column data to text (characters).
                    char *dbDataAsChars = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, i);

                    // If there are contents in the currenct column (field) then add them to the current row array.
                    if (dbDataAsChars != NULL) {
                        // Convert the characters to string.
                        [arrDataRow addObject:[NSString  stringWithUTF8String:dbDataAsChars]];
                    }

                    // Keep the current column name.
                    if (self.arrColumnNames.count != totalColumns) {
                        dbDataAsChars = (char *)sqlite3_column_name(compiledStatement, i);
                        [self.arrColumnNames addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:dbDataAsChars]];
                    }
                }

                // Store each fetched data row in the results array, but first check if there is actually data.
                if (arrDataRow.count > 0) {
                    [self.arrResults addObject:arrDataRow];
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            // This is the case of an executable query (insert, update, ...).

            // Execute the query.
            BOOL executeQueryResults = sqlite3_step(compiledStatement);
            if (executeQueryResults == SQLITE_DONE) {
                // Keep the affected rows.
                self.affectedRows = sqlite3_changes(sqlite3Database);

                // Keep the last inserted row ID.
                self.lastInsertedRowID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(sqlite3Database);
            }
            else {
                // If could not execute the query show the error message on the debugger.
                NSLog(@"DB Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3Database));
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        // In the database cannot be opened then show the error message on the debugger.
        NSLog(@"%s", sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3Database));
    }

    // Release the compiled statement from memory.
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

}

// Close the database.
sqlite3_close(sqlite3Database);
}
```

Comment: Lets start with `sqlite3_open()` does not return `BOOL`.  `SQLITE_OK` == GOOD == (BOOL)`NO`.

Comment: log the path of database and check database available or not?

Comment: how can i check database availablety

Comment: @NikhilDubey In copyDatabaseIntoDocumentsDirectory method available databasePath variable. that method aviable in DBManager class.

Comment: @iOSGuru the copyDatabaseIntoDocumentsDirectory available in my code the sourcePath    NSString *sourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseFilename];

Comment: ya log sourcepath variable.

Comment: and check it in finder, database is available or not ?

Comment: @iOSGuru i do not know  how to check it in finder

Comment: Gooood bro, open finder>Go>Go To Folder 
or
Open finder and swift+option+G

Comment: @iOSGuru i updated source Path and database path on code  NSString *sourcePath = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[self.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"cartdb.sql"]]; that for now BOOL openDatabaseResult is yes but BOOL prepareStatementResult still is No BOOL prepareStatementResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite3Database, query, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL);

Comment: @NikhilDubey sorry i can't understand what you say. and i just joking bro.

Comment: I'll say it again then.  `sqlite_xxx()` functions don't return `BOOL`.

Comment: @iOSGuru i update my code on databasePath then now BOOL openDatabaseResult is yes but still BOOL prepareStatementResult still is No think that should be also yes

Comment: @iOSGuru ok then what i have to do now to run this code

Comment: @NikhilDubey you not say to me path of database is available on finder or not.